# Как исправить ошибку подключения к PostgreSQL из Java

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

Пытаюсь подключиться к БД. jar файл подключил как библиотеку.
Вот соединение

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Test";
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("user","postgre");
        props.setProperty("password","3333");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("PostgreSQL JDBC driver not found.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Connection failure.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
}
```

В итоге вылетает ошибка следующая:

```
Connection failure.
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ВАЖНО: пользователь "postgre" не прошёл проверку подлинности (по паролю) (pgjdbc: autodetected server-encoding to be windows-1251, if the message is not readable, please check database logs and/or host, port, dbname, user, password, pg_hba.conf)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:514)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:141)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:192)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:454)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:256)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at Main.main(Main.java:13)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Пытался колдовать с кодировкой, но в итоге не разобрался. Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Как тебе помочь исправить ошибку пароля?

Comment: @RomanC думаете дело в пароле, имею в виду пароль правильный, я в с бд проверял, а вот из idea он не хочет соединяться

Comment: У меня точно такая проблема была, пришлось добавить креденциалы в базу данных и все заработало.

Answer (score 0):

На всякий случай отпишусь, потому что ответ не сразу нашелся:

1. Глянуть нет ли опечаток в настройках коннекта с PostgreSQL.
2. Если их нет, то тем же pgAdmin включить у пользователя `Can login`, на вкладке `Privileges`. Ну, или через консоль, кому как удобнее.
   [image: pgAdmin4]
3. Если и это не помогло, то стоит проверить у Intellij, всё ли в порядке с кодировкой в разделе `File Encodings`.